# How to disable multiple-scroll effect in osx and fire scroll event once per scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, mousewheel

I need to organise navigation like jquery.fullPage: when I scroll once - I move to next section.

I tried to use jquery.mousewheel for it, but it fails in MacOS with touchpad or trackpad or APPLE Magic Mouse: It scrolls multiple slides per one scroll.

I tried to use this solution: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/issues/36#issuecomment-67648897

It works fine in Chrome, but it does not in FF and has bugs in Safari.

This is simple demonstration of issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/ss5LueLx/13/

```
$slider.on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.deltaY>0) {
        slider.prevSlide();
    } else {
        slider.nextSlide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this statement in my SeaMonkey browser and it fails.

```
var delta  = e.type == 'mousewheel' ? e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1 : 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
```

Just in case, I looked at the deltaY and it works: +1 in one direction and -1 in the other, just as you determined in the other two implementations you have.

```
console.log(e.deltaY); // view console in FireBug
```

Looking at the event structure in Firebug, I can see that the event type is "mousewheel", and yet I do not see a wheelData field in the originalEvent.

And although there is a detail field, but that one remains at zero.

I would imagine that you are attempting to go to the next item only once you reach +/-3. I would suggest something of the sort to accomplish this feat:

```
// somewhere, initialize to zero
var current_position = 0;


// on mousewheel events
current_position += e.deltaY;

// you had a x 40 which would indicate that the limit is about 120 / 40
// if 3 is too small, you can always increase it to 5 or event 10...
if(current_position <= -3)
{
  slider.nextSlide();
  current_position = 0;
}
else if(current_position >= 3)
{
  slider.prevSlide();
  current_position = 0;
}
```

Otherwise you could verify that your `allowScroll` flag works as expected. I do not program objects that way so I am not too sure whether it is correct or not. (I use the `prototype` syntax which is useful if you want to extend classes.)